# C++ 1-100 guessing game where the computer is the one guessing

Tags: c++

I'm working through some questions in the text Principles and Practice using C++ and the specific question I'm having an issue with is the following. A user must think of a number between 1 and 100 then the computer will figure out what the question is by a series of guesses.

The current code works except for the number 1 (due to the rounding down of integers when dividing by 2). I can't seem to think of a way to fix this.

Here is the current source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const int MIN_VALUE = 1;

int guess;
int high = MAX_VALUE;
int low = MIN_VALUE;

char choice;

int main(){


cout<<"Think about a number between "<<MIN_VALUE<<" and "<<MAX_VALUE<<". \n\n";
guess = ( high-low ) / 2;

while((high-low)!=1){
    cout<<"Is your number less than or equal to "<<guess<<"? \nEnter y or n. \n\n";
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y') {
        high = guess;
        guess -= ( high - low ) / 2;
    }
    else if(choice=='n' || choice=='N') {
        low = guess;
        guess += (high - low ) /2;
    }
    else cout<<"Incorrect choice."<<endl;


}
cout<<"Your number is: "<<high<<".\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What's your input, what are the expected results, and what are the actual results?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it will work, but try tracking just the high and low values, and then calculate the "new guess" as `guess=(low + high)/2`...

Comment: Before looking at rest of the code, i feel the way you are arriving at the mid-point is lil fishy. (high-low) might be working for you here, but (high+low)/2 would be better way to get the mid point

Imagine you have to guess the number between 50 and 100. Your initial 'guess' will be (100-50)/2, which is 25 and youll never arrive at answer

Comment: Wherever you assign to `guess`, you want to have `guess = (high + low) / 2`. You are basically implementing a binary search and you want the midpoint of each range that you are looking at. The midpoint is `(high + low) / 2`.

Comment: Also, your exit condition can be something like `while(guess != high)`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure there's an error where max is sometimes inclusive and sometimes exclusive.  `high = MAX_VALUE;` is inclusive, but `high = guess;` is exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

What's your thinking behind choosing `while((high-low)!=1)` as your while expression?

Your code is basically saying - when the difference between `high` and `low` is 1, the correct number must be `high`. That's why it's not working when someone chooses the lowest value ( in this case 1 ).

You need to ensure that the lowest value `low` is presented to the user as a `guess`.

So - stepping through your code:

Let's use the example where you have a `MIN_VALUE` of 1, and the player has chosen 1 as their thought of number. Now, when `high` is 3 and `guess` is 2, you go through the while loop and because the player answers "Y" when asked if their chosen number is less than or equal to `guess`, `high` ends up as 2.

And interestingly `guess` stays at 2 because it gets reduced by `(high-low)/2`. Which rounds down to 0. This means that `guess` will never reach the lowest value - and this is a problem.

Continuing - next time your evaluate the while expression, it returns false ( because 2-1 == 1 ).

And you return `high` ( which is currently 2 ).

So I think you have 2 problems.

1) when you find yourself reducing `guess` by 0 then the player's thought of number *has* to be `low` and you should set `guess` to be `low` to allow this to be presented to the user as the computer's guess.

And 2) 
You need to find a way to allow your while loop to be entered, when the difference between `high` and `low` is 1. Which allows for the possibility of `guess` being presented to the player when it is equal to `low`.

Someone posted

```
while(high > low)
```

which I think is fine.

But you also need to check for when the difference between `high` and `low` is 1, because a) you don't want to just endlessly reduce `guess` by 0 and b) the thought of number *must* be `low` at this point.

So:

```
while((high>low){
    cout<<"Is your number less than or equal to "<<guess<<"? \nEnter y or n. \n\n"` ;
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y') {
        high = guess;
        if( high-low == 1)
        {
          guess = low;
        }
        else
        {
          guess -= ( high - low ) / 2; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: That made a lot of sense. Thanks for the detailed solution. It is working correctly now. :)

Comment: See my working answer, `while(high>low)` breaks it for all the other numbers and initial value for low has to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are three flaws in this program, but only one was adressed which will not work on its own:

- The correct exit condition for the loop is `while(guess>low)`, neither `while(high>low)` nor `while(guess!=high)` exit, except when the guessed number is 1 and `guess=low`.
- The minimum value has to be set to 0, `const int MIN_VALUE = 0;` otherwise you need 8 guesses for the number 1, but only 7 questions are allowed. It also prevents the loop from quitting before the condition for the number 1 is met:
- When the guessed number is reached, guess will be set to low and the loop exits:

  `if(high-low==1) guess=low;`
     `else guess -= ( high - low ) / 2;`

See the corrected and tested code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const int MIN_VALUE = 0;

int guess;
int high = MAX_VALUE;
int low = MIN_VALUE;

char choice;

int main(){


cout<<"Think about a number between "<<MIN_VALUE<<" and "<<MAX_VALUE<<". \n\n";
guess = ( high-low ) / 2;

while(guess>low){
    cout<<"Is your number less than or equal to "<<guess<<"? \nEnter y or n. \n\n";
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y') {
        high = guess;
        if(high-low==1) guess=low;
        else guess -= ( high - low ) / 2;
    }
    else if(choice=='n' || choice=='N') {
        low = guess;
        guess += (high - low ) /2;
    }
    else cout<<"Incorrect choice."<<endl;


}
cout<<"Your number is: "<<high<<".\n";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
while(high>low){
...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will fix the problem. What happens is that say our current guess is 2 with high being 2 and low being 1. Now by calculating the next guess value it will be (2-1)/2 which is 0.5 but that gets rounded down to 0 and the guess value stays at 2 (2-0=2) instead of 2-0.5=1.5 which will get rounded down to 1. Hope that made things clearer.

Comment: how about rounding the `high` up?

Answer (score -1):

Just change the min value to 0 and the problem would be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).